# Cloning a branch without merging main branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Sometimes I want to be able to pull from a repo (via clone). But when I do that and then change to a local branch to pull-in a remote branch, git assumes I want to take the main branch and integrate it. How do I avoid this? I'm sure I can achieve what I want by a different series of actions/commands.

I'd say I normally run into this when I want to work on a specific branch on a secondary machine.

**update**:
I run the following commands on a secondary machine where I only want to work on the experiment branch

```
git clone http://somewhere.com/something.git    
git branch experiment    
git checkout experiment   
git pull origin experiement
```

Comment: could you show the exact commands you are executing, and what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Agreed.  Need an example.  Simply cloning and changing branches shouldn't force any automatic "integration".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each branch needs to point at some commit. If you don’t specify anything, `git branch` points the new branch at at the same commit as HEAD.

You want the branch to point at `origin/experiment` instead:

```
git clone http://somewhere.com/something.git
cd something
git branch experiment origin/experiment
git checkout experiment
```

or…

```
git clone http://somewhere.com/something.git
cd something
git checkout -b experiment origin/experiment
```

or, since git is smart enough to know what you’re trying to do in this case…

```
git clone http://somewhere.com/something.git
cd something
git checkout experiment
```

All of these will do the same thing (create the new branch pointing at `origin/experiment`). They’ll also set the branch up to *track* `origin/experiment`, so push and pull will be to and from that remote branch.

Comment: does that allow you to use the shorter syntax for your push and pulls without typing the remote branch name?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the branches from the remote or remotes without merging anything you can just do a

```
git fetch --all
```

or

```
git fetch [remote]
```

I usually just open the git gui and click remotes>fetch>[remote] and then I use

```
gitk --all
```

to see what is done on the remote branches.
I can then merge if I want to... 
git pull means a fetch+merge